# Space where any metric can not be defined

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Is there some space where any metric function can not be defined?

I am currently studying topological vector spaces and read if a topological vector space has countable base it has a compatible metric with the topology. I am trying to look for some examples of topology where any compatible metric cannot be defined. I am trying for vector spaces with uncountable basis.

Also generalizing this I was thinking whether there are sone spaces where no metric function can be defined.

Comment: Indiscrete topology.

Comment: Consider the weak topology on $\ell^1$.

Comment: Wikipedia states a number of non-metrizable spaces. It's good to have a look at the metrization theorems. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrization_theorem#Metrization_theorems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean a vector space, then YES, you can always define a metric there. In fact, there is no need to assume a vector space structure: If $X$ is any given set, then the function $d:X\times X \to \Bbb R$ defined as.

$$d(x,y)=0 \;\textrm{ if } x=y, \;\; d(x,y)=1\;\textrm{ if } x\neq y,$$ defines a metric on $X.$

If what you are given is a topological vector space then, as Rustyn pointed out, you need to check metrization theorems.